# Show that $E[X_t^2]<\infty$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Show that $E[X_t^2]<\infty$, where
$$
X_t=e^{3W_t-\frac{3t}{2}}-3e^{W_t-\frac{t}{2}}\underbrace{\int_0^te^{2W_s-s}ds}_{A_t},\quad. t\geq0,
$$
where $t$ is a fixed number and $W_t$ is Brownian motion.
What I did was:

1. By Itō's formula: $X_t=\int_0^t\left(3e^{3W_s-\frac{3s}{2}}-3e^{W_s-\frac{s}{2}}A_s\right)dW_s$
2. Itō isometry:

\begin{align*}
E[X_t^2]&=E\left[\left(\int_0^t\left(3e^{3W_s-\frac{3s}{2}}-3e^{W_s-\frac{s}{2}}A_s\right)dW_s\right)^2\right]\\[1.ex]
&=E\left[\int_0^t\left(3e^{3W_s-\frac{3s}{2}}-3e^{W_s-\frac{s}{2}}A_s\right)^2ds\right]\\[1.ex]
&= ...\\[1.ex]
&= \int_0^t\left(9e^{-3s}\underbrace{E\left[e^{6W_s}\right]}_{=e^{18s}}-18e^{-2s}\underbrace{E\left[e^{4W_s}A_s\right]}_{(1)}+9e^{-s}\underbrace{E\left[e^{2W_s}A_s^2\right]}_{(2)}\right)ds
\end{align*}

My main problem is that I don't know how to make an estimation of $(1)$ and $(2)$. I've tried using Cauchy-Schwarz, but it does not help me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in order to apply Itô's formula you already have to *know* that the integrands are suitable integrable.

Comment: I'm kind of new to stochastics, so I don't quite understand what you think. If I understand you correctly, I can't show that $E[X_t^2]<\infty$ the way I imagined to do it?

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful. I'll write an answer (... in some hours, I guess).

Comment: Thanks, you are really saving me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me remark that applying Itô's formula is really overkill (and not necessary at all). In my answer you will see that the expressions (1) and (2) defined in your question are in fact finite, so you can prove it this way - but as I said, I do not recommend to do so.

---

In order to show $X_t \in L^2$, it suffices to prove

$$Y_t := e^{3W_t-3t/2} \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$$

and

$$Z_t := 3 e^{W_t-t/2} A_t \in L^2(\mathbb{P}).$$

Recall that $W_t$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t$. This implies $\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda W_t}< \infty$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$; in fact, the exponential moments can be calculated explicitly:

$$\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda W_t} = \exp \left( \frac{\lambda^2}{2} t \right) \tag{1}$$

(see e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions)). Therefore,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t^2) = e^{-3t} \mathbb{E}e^{6W_t} < \infty,$$

i.e. $Y_t \in L^2$. To show that $Z_t$ is square-integrable, we apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\mathbb{E}(Z_t^2) \leq 3 \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(e^{4W_t-2t})} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(A_t^2)}.$$

As above, we have $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(e^{4W_t-2t})}<\infty$. Consequently, it remains to show that $\mathbb{E}(A_t^2)<\infty$. Applying Jensen's inequality yields

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(A_t^2) &= \mathbb{E} \left( \left|  t \int_0^t e^{2W_s-s} \, \frac{ds}{t} \right|^2 \right) \\ &\leq t \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t (e^{2W_s-s})^2 \, ds \right) \\ &\leq t \int_0^t \mathbb{E}e^{4W_s} \, ds. \end{align*}$$

Using $(1)$ we get $\mathbb{E}(A_t^2)<\infty$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks @saz. I have only one question. Lets say $X$ is some random variable written in the form of $X=Z+W$, where $Z$ and $W$ are r.v. In general if I want to proof that $X\in L^2$ then if suffices to prove that $Z$ and $W$ are $L^2$, respectively?

Comment: @Kyoto Yes, this follows from the triangle inequality (aka Minkowski's inequality): $$\|X\|_{L^2} = \|Z+W\|_{L^2} \leq \|Z\|_{L^2} + \|W\|_{L^2}.$$

Comment: It's good to know that. Thank you once again!